# What does the instance argument in Python's create_autospec do?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm playing around with mock autospecs in Python. Here's a basic test case where I'm autospecing the Django `User` class using [create_autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#create-autospec).

```
from unittest.mock import create_autospec
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def test_mock_spec():
    user = create_autospec(User, spec_set=True, instance=True, username="batman")
    assert user.username == "batman"
    with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
        create_autospec(User, spec_set=True, x1=1)
    with pytest.raises(AttributeError):
        assert user.x2
```

The test passes when I set both `instance=True` and `instance=False`, so what exactly does this parameter do? What's its purpose? I've seen multiple blog posts set it to `True` ([here](https://blog.thea.codes/my-python-testing-style-guide/#a-mock-must-always-have-a-spec) and [here](https://www.seanh.cc/2017/03/17/the-problem-with-mocks/)) so I feel like it's important.

The documentation says the following but it doesn't make sense to me:

> If a class is used as a spec then the return value of the mock (the instance of the class) will have the same spec. You can use a class as the spec for an instance object by passing instance=True. The returned mock will only be callable if instances of the mock are callable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider mocking the `int` class. `int` is callable, like most classes, so a mock of the `int` class should also be callable.

On the other hand, consider mocking an `int` instance. Integers are *not* callable, so a mock of an integer should also not be callable.

The `instance` argument lets you control which of these behaviors you get. `create_autospec(int, instance=False)` returns a callable mock, while `create_autospec(int, instance=True)` returns a non-callable mock. If you do

```
m1 = create_autospec(int, instance=False)
m2 = create_autospec(int, instance=True)

m1()
m2()
```

only the `m2()` line will raise an exception.

Comment: One additional aspect is that `spec`, the first parameter to `create_autospec` (I think of it as short for "specimen"), can be an _instance_ as well as a class. This is handy for a dataclass, for example, when the defined attributes cannot be inferred from the class. It that case, as I read the source, the value of the `instance` parameter is ignored, behaving like it was set to `True`. Specifying an instance may be more cumbersome, although providing `None` for all its parameters often works fine for me, but is good to have for cases where instance attributes are used as interface.